# docker: tomcat java heap space Out Of Memory

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, heap-memory

Tomcat memory settings:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

When running on docker for days, the following error will occur:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

But if running on host for months, no such error.

Is memory managed differently on docker?

Java 11.

Tomcat container memory size is not set. Default to about 3.7G (host memory size 4G).

```
$ sudo docker stats

CONTAINER ID   NAME    CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O        PIDS

fab6ccf50ec5   tomcat   0.30%     1.158GiB / 3.775GiB   30.67%    56.5MB / 1.61GB   74.7MB / 0B      15024
```

When heap space Out Of memory occurred, the tomcat container process was not killed. container memory: 30% used.

Comment: "Is memory managed differently on docker?"  Yes, and it also depends on the version of Java.  See, for example, https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker

Comment: Thanks for info. But it seems to be a different issue. From docker stats, container memory limit is about 4G, 30% used. The tomcat container was not killed. Java 11.